# Bean listener does not get invoked when data table is sorted

Tags: jsf, listener

I am displaying data in a JSF data table:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{mailServices.mailServices}" var="s">
    <p:column headerText="ID" sortBy="#{s.ID}">
        #{s.ID}
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{s.name}">
        #{s.name}
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Aktiv" sortBy="#{s.startup}">
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{s.startup}" >
            <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{mailServices.toggleMailService}"/>
            <f:attribute name="serviceid" value="#{s.ID}"/>
        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

As long as i do not click on the column headers the listener gets invoked when clicking a checkbox. But as soon as I have sorted a column (no matter what column it is) the listener does not get invoked.

My listener looks like:

```
public void toggleMailService(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {
    //code
}
```

Could it be that I am using the `<f:ajax event...>` wrongly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

What @BalusC said, tag  is missing a left bracket:

```
<f:ajax event="change" listener="#MailServices.toggleMailService}"/>
```

Try with

```
<f:ajax event="change" listener="#{MailServices.toggleMailService}"/>
```

Also asure that your Bean is being declared as "MailServices"

```
@ManagedBean(name="MailServices")
```

Comment: Hi Laiv, i edited the post. This was simply a typo. In real code left bracket is not missing. In addition to that i also edited the "MailServices" in code to be in lower-case now (which also was a typo). Thanks.